# Bound Mismatch Linked List Java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, stack

I am working on an assignment to make a stack in java using Linked Lists, but there is an error I am getting, which prevents me from doing anything. 
here is first of all the Node class

```
public class SortedLinkedSetNode<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    protected T value;
    protected  SortedLinkedSetNode<T> next;
    // other methods
}
```

now here is the Stack class , of which I will only give the Push method because an error occurs there.

```
 public class StackList<E> implements Stack<E> {
     protected SortedLinkedSetNode upperMost;
     public void push( E element) {
        SortedLinkedSetNode <E> newNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode (element);
        newNode.next = upperMost;
        upperMost = newNode;    
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i try to make the newNode inside Push i get this message :

```
Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type  SortedLinkedSetNode<T>
```

I tried modifying the stack class so that it is

```
public class StackList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Stack<E> {
```

but i am NOT allowed to modify it (thats just the assignment specification). I also tried using T not using anything and all sorts of combinations but there is always an error. I think that it all comes from this (which is given)

```
public class SortedLinkedSetNode<T extends Comparable<T>>{
```

but am not sure, and also not sure what to do if it really is from here
 Can someone help me out with what exactly this is , and how i could solve it. If i can't make a new node in the stack class how can i even begin doing Push Pop etc.. ? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you have ```public class StackList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Stack<E extends Comparable<E>>``` ?

Comment: You can't have a `SortedLinkedSetNode` inside a `Stack<E>`. That also doesn't make sense. You should just have plain `LinkedSetNode<T>` there. If you want to have a `SortedLinkedSetNode`, you got to have a `Stack` that requires comparable objects. You got to make the type arguments compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You have made your `SortedLinkedSetNode` class generic, with an upper bound on `T`.  However, when you attempt to use the class with `E` in `StackList`, you didn't declare `E` with the same upper bound, resulting in a bound mismatch.  Try adding the upper bound to `E` on `StackList`:

```
public class StackList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Stack<E> {
```

Also, the `SortedLinkedSetNode` class is generic, but you are inconsistently applying a generic type parameter to your code that uses the class.

When declaring the variable `upperMost`, use `<E>`:

```
protected SortedLinkedSetNode<E> upperMost;
```

Additionally, add `<E>` to when you create a new `SortedLinkedSetNode` (could be the diamond "operator" `<>` if you're using Java 1.7+).

```
SortedLinkedSetNode<E> newNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode<E> (element);
```

Answer (score 0):

*"The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type  SortedLinkedSetNode"* means that `E` is more generic than `T extends Comparable<T>`. You're declaring that your generic type `T` must `extend Comparable<T>`, while `<E>` doesn't have such limitation, and as such, `E` is invalid for your `SortedLinkedSetNode<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

If you can't modify the Stack class, then you have no choice than to change your class to

```
public class SortedLinkedSetNode<T>
```

Also you need to use `<E>` in your object instantiation

```
new SortedLinkedSetNode<E>(element);
```